# How should we tag questions about time constraints?

Tags: discussion, tags

I came across the question, [How many encounters can you squeeze into a 3 hour slot?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1401/how-many-encounters-can-you-squeeze-into-a-3-hour-slot), while removing the old-school tag. Its only tags were old-school and convention. Neither of those really seem to apply. I think it is a good question with some valuable answers. Any idea how questions like this should be tagged?

Answer (score 1):

Broadly speaking, I think every question "about time constraints" is going to be about some activity that you're trying to accomplish within those time constraints. I think it's natural to tag those questions based on the underlying activity. Here, there are really two activities - "running encounters" and "designing a scenario." The former is actually constrained, time-wise, but the latter is taking those constraints into account. At its core, the question is "about" scenario design, so I think scenario-development applies pretty strongly, here. If it were a question about what the longest real-time span a campaign could realistically cover (Is it OK if I run a campaign for a decade?) then it would be campaign-development, I guess. If it were "how long can a dude dither about which square he's going to move his character into before he passes his turn," well, that's a mechanics question, I guess, and I'm not sure we have a tag for system-agnostic questions about how to manage the table.

This particular question wasn't system-agnostic, incidentally; but it did specify two distinct possible systems. I assume questions should be tagged with all the systems they purport to apply to. I went ahead and added add1.0, but the tagging convention for systems is still far too up-in-the-air for me to guess what the appropriate tag for S&W might be.

Comment: I think S&W would be [odd].